# Cant connect to MS Access db in network server using excel vb

Tags: excel, ms-access, connection-string, vba

This is the connection string from Excel VBA to MS Access

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=\\10.123.24.44\MS\Test.mdb
```

Comment: Works for me. "Cant connect" is not a good description of an error.

Comment: I receive the following error:
error no:80004005
could not find installable ISAM
@GSerg

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution

1) your computer must within the same workgroup

2)use the  Microsoft Office Access Database engine 5.0 reference instead of Microsoft Activex

3) here is the Connection

public sub connectToMSAccessDB()

dim db as database

dim rs as record set

dim path as string

path=" \\servername or ip\\sharedfolder\filename

set db=OpenDatabase(path)

set rs=db.openRecordSet("Your Query")

'and enjoy it

end sub